# Set scroll position

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set the scroll position on a page so the scroller is scrolled all the way to the top.

I think I need something like this but it's not working:

```
(function () { alert('hello'); document.body.scrollTop = 0; } ());
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

You can use [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo), like this:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0); // values are x,y-offset
```

Answer (score 61):

Also worth noting `window.scrollBy(dx,dy)` ([ref](http://javascript.gakaa.com/window-scrollby-4-0-5-.aspx))

Answer (score 60):

Note that if you want to scroll an element instead of the full window, elements don't have the `scrollTo` and `scrollBy` methods. You should:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myel"); // Or whatever method to get the element

// To set the scroll
el.scrollTop = 0;
el.scrollLeft = 0;

// To increment the scroll
el.scrollTop += 100;
el.scrollLeft += 100;
```

You can also mimic the `window.scrollTo` and `window.scrollBy` functions to all the existant HTML elements in the webpage on [browsers that don't support it natively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo#browser_compatibility):

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "scrollTo", {
    value: function(x, y) {
        this.scrollTop = y;
        this.scrollLeft = x;
    },
    enumerable: false
});

Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "scrollBy", {
    value: function(x, y) {
        this.scrollTop += y;
        this.scrollLeft += x;
    },
    enumerable: false
});
```

so you can do:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myel"); // Or whatever method to get the element, again

// To set the scroll
el.scrollTo(0, 0);

// To increment the scroll
el.scrollBy(100, 100);
```

NOTE: `Object.defineProperty` is encouraged, as directly adding properties to the `prototype` is a breaking bad habit (When you see it :-).

Comment: This was helpfull, thanks. But I found that elements do have the 'scrollTo' method. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Comment: @Narvalex that's what the second paragraph states.

Comment: The reference that I pointed out shows that those functions are built-in. No need to define properties of built-in methods

Comment: @Narvalex Oh, I've just read "don't have", my bad. I must state that not all browsers have it then, although nowadays is difficult to find such browser (like IE11).

Answer (score 6):

... Or just replace `body` by `documentElement`:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: I like this solution over the selected one more, as 1. It is more inline with what OP wanted to do in the first place, 2. Also allows reading the value of the scroll position

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the scroll position of `document.body`, you can scroll the entire `window` altogether using [**`window.scrollTo()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo); it takes either a pair of coordinates (x,y) or an options object – if you just want to scroll nicely to the top, try `window.scrollTo({top:0,behavior:'smooth'});`.

However, in some instances, you have an *element* to scroll (and not the entire document). For that case, elements also provide a [**`scrollTo()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) method using the same arguments.

```
document.querySelector('ul#list').scrollTo(0,0);
```