# How to set scrollbar to top of section / forget scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jQuery UI Accordion. One section has a scroll bar. I would like that scroll bar to default to the top every time that section is opened. Currently, it "remembers" its previous position. Is there a way to make it forget its position or always default to the top. I only want to set this for the particular section, not the entire page.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192847/set-scroll-position) suggests using `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` to force the page to scroll to the top. But I'm unsure how to apply that to only a particular section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the scroll position of .ui-accordion-content to 0 at the accordion's change or changestart event.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to provide an example?

Comment: Hm i tried it now but i can't  reproduce your problem. It scrolls up automatically for me, maybe your markup is different or your jqUI version? Anyway i made an example of how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/8kgjG/1/ (i set the scrollTop to 50 here)

Comment: When I first opened the section, the scroll position would be at the top, but would always be located towards the bottom when I reopened the section. In any case, your solution fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Yes that's because i set the position only at the change event so it startet at the top, and at the event it's set to 50. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

set the [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop)-property of the element to 0