# Input focus using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to use javascript focus on an input without having the page scroll. I would like to have the curser start in the input field but I don't want it to scroll to that part of the page.

currently I am using

```
function setFocusToTextBox() {
    document.getElementById("FirstName1").focus();
}
```

Comment: Instead, why not give the input focus once it becomes visible in the viewport? This way you avoid the whole issue of the page jumping down to the input, and offers a better experience.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: That would be the basis of another question, but you would have to [calculate if the element is outside of the viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport) (and probably need to bind this function to the `window.scroll` event), and when the element is not outside of the viewport, give it focus like you're already doing.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith did you try my answer it should work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the scroll before then set the scroll after like this:

```
function setFocusToTextBox() {
    var doc = document.documentElement;
    var x = (window.pageXOffset || doc.scrollLeft) - (doc.clientLeft || 0);
    var y = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);
    document.getElementById("FirstName1").focus();
    window.scrollTo(x, y);
}
```

Code take from these links: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3464890/4028085)   [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4192861/4028085)

You can get the scroll location before the `focus` then set it back to what it was right after you `focus`...

Comment: I am currently trying it, the page scrolls to the top but there is no cursor on in the text field so I am trying to work through what you gave me and see if I am doing something incorrectly.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I did a simple test on my machine and it worked...The scroll stayed where it was and the cursor was in the `<input>` field...Maybe you have something else different. I will post a fiddle for you.

Comment: Yeah, I obviously have another issue. I will post when I can figure out WTH is going on.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith if you want go ahead and post more code in your question if it's not too much just post your full page...

Comment: Ok, I am am going to mark your answer correct because it does answer my question. its not working for me on that page but I think its now due to having multiple different page scroll functions and one is overriding the other, today will be one of those days I guess.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith haha! it happens man...thanks and good luck!