# How can I implement smooth scrolling on my webpage in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a long webpage, so I thought about introducing table of contents. Now I would like to - instead of just jumping to a new place in the webpage - scroll there smoothly. I saw lots of tutorials of how to navigate to a specific place from the nav bar, but I would like to do it from the normal hyperlinks on the webpage.

In my html so far I have:

```
<h4>contents</h4>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#part1">part1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#part2">part2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#part3">part3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#part4">part4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#part5">part5</a></li>
 </ul>

<div class="row" id="part1">
    <h4>lorem ipsum</h4>
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="row" id="part2">
    <h4>lorem ipsum</h4>
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="row" id="part3">
    <h4>lorem ipsum</h4>
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="row" id="part4">
    <h4>lorem ipsum</h4>
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Is there any native bootstrap way of implementing the smooth scrolling? or maybe is there any js script that I could somehow adjust for myself?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for that in jQuery called **animate**.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#myId").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

You can change the duration according to your taste.

Comment: oh ok, good to know :) but how can I apply it to a several `#myId` links?

Answer (score 0):

There is another question that might help you get exactly what you want, but window.scrollTo() seems like what you are looking for! [Here's the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192847/set-scroll-position)

Comment: Thanks, but how will I know the offset? :) is there a way of just putting the id of a div instead of the offset?